# Invalid Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, iphone, delphi, code-signing, firemonkey

I developed a multi-platform app in Rad Studio XE5 and successfully deployed it to the Google Play Store for Android. I have also successfully deployed it to my iPad with a development cert.

Now when I try and load the application to iTunes via Application Loader I get the following error: [image]

Here is my deers in Rad Studio:

[image]

I have tried Downloading a new Prov Profile and i also tried matching the CFBundleName and Bundle Identifier with different values.

Here is a screenshot of my app in iTunes Connect:

[image]

Comment: you are using the development profile. please use the Adhoc profile for making the binary to upload on iTunes

Comment: where do i change that? cos in Rad Studio i am definitely pointing towards my Distribution Profile under the Provisioning.